# Change direction of angles in Highcharts

Tags: charts, highcharts

I have a chart in Highcharts, but I need the angles starting at x like the chart below. How can I do it?

original chart:

[image]

need this chart:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this an output that you wanted to achieve?

Config:

```
pane: {
    startAngle: 90,
    endAngle: 450
},

xAxis: {
    tickInterval: 30,
    min: 0,
    max: 360,
    labels: {
        format: '{value}°'
    },
            reversed: true
},
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n79vcwkm/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/pane.startAngle

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.reversed